# CSS Only SlideShow with dynamic # of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a CSS Only SlideShow on a page that I am creating. The slides are added dynamically, and that is causing an issue with displaying the slides properly. Below is the CSS and HTML I am using.

My hopes were the code would handle a Max of 20 Images and the timing would be 4 seconds between each image. The issue I am facing is that the images, when dynamically added, do not play in order, which I was expected.

Does anybody have a clue why this code does not work correctly? The slide show plays perfectly, it is only the order of images being shown that is off. I should also add that there are multiple slide shows on the same page. I'm not sure if that may be causing the issue.

I have noticed that when images are skipped, there is a flash between images during the actual transition.

```css
.slider {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.photo {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: round 16s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes round {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.slider img:nth-child(20) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 76s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 76s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 76s;
 -o-animation-delay: 76s;
 animation-delay: 76s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(19) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 72s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 72s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 72s;
 -o-animation-delay: 72s;
 animation-delay: 72s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(18) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 68s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 68s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 68s;
 -o-animation-delay: 68s;
 animation-delay: 68s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(17) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 64s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 64s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 64s;
 -o-animation-delay: 64s;
 animation-delay: 64s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(16) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
 -o-animation-delay: 60s;
 animation-delay: 60s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(15) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 56s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 56s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 56s;
 -o-animation-delay: 56s;
 animation-delay: 56s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(14) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 52s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 52s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 52s;
 -o-animation-delay: 52s;
 animation-delay: 52s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(13) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 48s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 48s;
 -o-animation-delay: 48s;
 animation-delay: 48s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(12) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 44s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 44s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 44s;
 -o-animation-delay: 44s;
 animation-delay: 44s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(11) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 40s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 40s;
 -o-animation-delay: 40s;
 animation-delay: 40s;
}

slider img:nth-child(10) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
 -o-animation-delay: 36s;
 animation-delay: 36s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(9) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
 -o-animation-delay: 32s;
 animation-delay: 32s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(8) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 28s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 28s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 28s;
 -o-animation-delay: 28s;
 animation-delay: 28s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(7) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
 -o-animation-delay: 24s;
 animation-delay: 24s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 20s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 20s;
 -o-animation-delay: 20s;
 animation-delay: 20s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
 -o-animation-delay: 16s;
 animation-delay: 16s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
 -o-animation-delay: 12s;
 animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
 -o-animation-delay: 8s;
 animation-delay: 8s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
 -o-animation-delay: 4s;
 animation-delay: 4s;
}

.slider img:nth-child(1) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 -o-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8562523343_9bb49b7b7b.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo' src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: How are they being dynamically added?

Comment: It;s work correct ... how images added?

Comment: They are added in a for each loop that pulls the images from a BCC field. I am working with .JSP Pages using ATG Platform. There are multiple slide shows on the same page, would that have anything to do with my issue?